# Are Distributions just functions with infinitesimal coefficients?

Tags: distribution-theory, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

It is relatively well known that the Dirac delta, the classical example of a distribution, can be written as
$$ 
\frac{a}{π(a^2+x^2)}
$$
where $a$ is an infinitesimal such as a hyperreal. This can be confirmed by simply integrating and evaluating the integral symmetrically about the y axis which is simply $\frac{\arctan(x/a)}{π}$ from $x=-b$ to $x=b$ with $b$ real which is of course equal to $1$.

My question is if this holds generally.  Are there any distributions of note that cannot be written as straightforward functions in a setting equipped with infinitesimals?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. But I'm left wondering whether you can describe the (distributional) derivative of Dirac delta this way also?

Comment: Just an idea: every distribution with compact support is a sum of derivatives of continuous functions. Using actual infinitesimals, those derivatives are "normal" functions of real and hyperreal arguments. So I think in this case at least your claim seems correct.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen throwing $-\frac{\left(2ax\right)}{\pi\left(a^{2}+x^{2}\right)^{2}}$, the derivative of the function I gave, into desmos seems to give about the right shape for small positive numbers.

Comment: It looks like your question can be reworded as "Are there any distributions that cannot be written as a limit of (continuous) functions?"

Comment: @md2perpe Ok.  Are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every distribution can be written as a limit of smooth functions:

Let $u\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb R)$ and $\eta\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R).$ Then let $\eta_\epsilon(x) = \frac1\epsilon\eta(\frac x \epsilon)$ and $u_\epsilon=u*\eta_\epsilon.$ Then $u_\epsilon\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and $u_\epsilon\to u$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb R)$ as $\epsilon\to 0.$

Answer (score 2):

I have several related remarks.

1. The (internal) function $\delta_a(x)=\frac{a}{π(a^2+x^2)}$ you mentioned (for $a$ infinitesimal) will have the property that, when integrating it against any continuous function $f$, one will get $f(0)$ but *only up to an infinitesimal*, so that $\int \delta_a(x) f(x)dx \approx f(0)$.  This was already mentioned in Robinson's 1966 book.
2. There is later work whereby you can get a delta function satisfying equality on the nose, but this requires more effort.
3. An interesting question is to gauge how much choice one would need to get such a delta function via infinitesimals.  This may depend on the boundary conditions one chooses and what class of functions exactly one is dealing with.  For example, the theory [SCOT](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/infinitesimals.html#21e) is conservative over ZF+ADC (where ADC is axiom of dependent choice), but it may be too weak to construct such a delta function.

Comment: But when you evaluate an integral your taking a standard part, so shouldn't the infinitesimal get rounded off anyway?  Or does something about having infinitesimal coefficients prevent that from happening?

Comment: The integral is a certain map from a suitable space of functions to $\mathbb R$.   Integration "against" a function is another such map.  What one can show is that for a suitable choice of a delta-function, integration of a standard function $f$ against it will give precisely the value of $f$ at the point.  Here the delta-function is necessarily an internal function (not standard).  There is work by Todor Todorov in this area, as well as other mathematicians.  I don't know how much can be done in SCOT (i.e., conservatively over ZF+ADC).  @DanielSchwartz